# Storing Bank Account Number and Sort-code in the Database

Tags: security, bank

I need to store UK Bank Account Number and Sort Code in my MYSQL database to send the users payments.

The PHP/Laravel site will be hosted on AWS with SSL & off-course the Account Number and Sort Code will be encrypted (Mcrypt) when stored in the Database, in a separate table to the users table.

The end-users will be forced to use the HTTPS version of the site.

My Question:
Do I need to be PCI compliant for this? or is there any other law related issues that I need to look into before?

I have been searching all-day and have not found any solid answers hence this post.

Kind regards

Comment: I do not think the tags `php` and `pci` apply to this question. For answer these tags are not relevant.

Comment: May be better to ask on https://law.stackexchange.com/ But its defintiely not a SO question